# How to enable AMP / accelerated mobile pages in joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, gantry, amp

is there any plugin which is able to render any existing template into a AMP / accelerated mobile page?

I use mostly gantry for theming and would like to enable AMP for all my managed pages.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few extensions that can help enable AMP for Joomla. Here are some:

- [wbAMP Community Edition](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/wbamp-community-edition) (Free)
- [wbAMP](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/wbamp) (Paid)
- [Accelerated Mobile Pages](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/accelerated-mobile-pages) (Paid)
- [JAmp](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jamp) (Paid)

This is not an exhaustive list and you should probably [search the JED](https://extensions.joomla.org) to see if there is anything else more suitable.

Comment: strange, I did it yesterday. And I also searched on google along with stackexchange search. Anyway thank you for pointing to the solutions